# Standard "check-all" functionality in table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here's a part of my grid (CRUD) component:

```
<template>
  <table class="MyComponent table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="30px">
          <b-form-checkbox v-model="allChecked" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(record, index) in records" :key="index">
        <td width="30px">
          <b-form-checkbox :value="record['id']" v-model="checkedRows" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  components: {
  },
  props: ['config'],
  data() {
    return {
      records: [{
        id: 1
      }, {
        id: 2
      }, {
        id: 3
      }, {
        id: 4
      }, {
        id: 5
      }, {
        id: 6
      }],
      checkedRows: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    allChecked: {
      get() {
        return this.records.length == this.checkedRows.length
      },
      set(v) {
        if(v) {
          this.checkedRows = [];
          for(var i in this.records) {
            this.checkedRows.push(this.records[i]['id'])
          }
        }
        else {
          this.checkedRows = [];
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

As you can see, I would like to achive a standard, widely used functionality: The user can check multiple rows and do some operation with the selected rows. The problem is with the "check all" checkbox on the top of the table. When I check all, then I remove the tick from only one checkbox below, it unchecks all the checkboxes on page.

I understand why its happening: When I remove a tick from on of the checkboxes below, the "this.records.length == this.checkedRows.length" condition will no longer be true, so the "allChecked" computed variable will be set to false, therefore the top checkbox will set to unchecked. The problem is: when the top checkbox will be unchecked, then all of the checkboxes will be unchecked as well, because of the "set" part of the computed variable.

Is there a *clean* way to solve this problem in Vue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the checked rows, but maybe this will be better:

```
<b-form-checkbox :value="record['id']" v-model="record.checked" />
```

Then add to your objects in `records` a `checked` property.

```
records: [
    {
        id: 1,
        checked: false
    },
    ...
]
```

and if you need a list of checked records you might do a computed property:

```
computed: {
    checkedRecords() {
        return this.records.filter(record => record.checked);
    }
}
```

and for checking-unchecking all you just iterate over all records:

```
<b-form-checkbox @change="clickedAll" />

methods: {
    clickedAll(value) {
        this.records = this.records.map(record => {
              record.checked = value
              return record
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it not works, and it loses an important feature as well. The v-model saves values into array in checkboxes (see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), so the "record.checked" for the v-model is not a good solution. The other problem with this is the following: I would like to check the "top" checkbox, when the user manually checks all the checkboxes below (so if I have 10 rows, and I check all 10 checkboxes on the begenning of the rows, the "top" checkbox should be checked as well).

Comment: The second problem can be solved easily, but with the first one I didn't understand why it doesn't suit your needs? Yes, it does save the value into the array so it can be bound to the checkboxes and be reactive. That's the point. Would you explain some more why it's not acceptable?

Comment: Ok, I see you found your own solution. Cool. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, meanwhile I solved the problem. Here's my solution. Thanks @Eggon for your help, you gave the idea to use the @change method.

```
    <template>
      <table class="MyComponent table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="30px">
              <b-form-checkbox v-model="allChecked" @change="checkAll" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(record, index) in records" :key="index">
            <td width="30px">
              <b-form-checkbox :value="record['id']" v-model="checkedRows" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "MyComponent",
      components: {
      },
      props: ['config'],
      data() {
        return {
          records: [{
            id: 1
          }, {
            id: 2
          }, {
            id: 3
          }, {
            id: 4
          }, {
            id: 5
          }, {
            id: 6
          }],
          checkedRows: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        checkAll(value) {
          if(!value) {
            this.checkedRows = [];
            return ;
          }
    
          var newCheckedRows = [];
          for(var i in this.records) {
            newCheckedRows.push(this.records[i].id)
          }
          this.checkedRows = newCheckedRows;
        }
      },
      computed: {
        allChecked: {
          get() {
            return this.records.length == this.checkedRows.length
          },
          set() {
            
          }
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm curious - does it really work `v-model="checkedRows"`? I wouldn't expect this - you're binding a single property that is multiplied many times by `v-for` to an empty array. I don't understand how they can bind properly.

Comment: @Eggon It works that way when you use multiple checkboxes with the same v-model property and with different :value property for each checkbox. You can find the documentation here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox, under the "multiple checkbox" section. 
I tried both solution, yours and mine as well. Your solution didn't work, because the record.checked gets the :value property from the checkbox (which is an id in your case), but you use it like its a boolean.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks, I didn't know checkboxes can be bound this way. It's curious, because in the docs you linked there's an example with a single checkbox where it's done my way, but the value is not defined there. Maybe it would work better this way: `b-form-checkbox v-model="record.checked"`. However even if value is ID it kind of should work anyway, as ID is truthy? But nevermind. :) Good luck with your project!